# Facebook comments plugin in handlebars script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, handlebars.js

I want to use the Facebook comments box on my WordPress page where I use "handlebars js", which dynamically loads my HTML content with a script on my page.

When I add the Facebook html code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mysite/mypage/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

anywhere on the page it works fine, but when I use it within the handlebars script, it does not (except for like 1 time out of 20!).

I have tried changing the Facebook JS SDK to load asynchronously, as I suspect the issue has to do with the order in which my scripts are loaded, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the plugin with [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after appending the Handelbars content to the DOM. Btw, that´s another topic, but you should ALWAYS load the JS SDK asynchronously, and make sure it is loaded before using FB.XFBML.parse.

Make sure to call the parse function after appending the Template content to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, but now another question popped up. Adding FB.XFBML.parse(); only works when I add it within the handlebars script - but then it keeps reloading and the page never loads completely. Enqueueing the parse script did not work..

Comment: it should work after appending the handlebars content, that´s how i do it with handlebars. it is very important that you call it when the content is in the DOM already. you could add the code parts where you are using the parse function in your question, if you want me to take a look.

Comment: My handlebars script imports rows from a spreadsheet and makes them into individual divs on my page. So three rows with data = three text boxes. I want a FB comment box in each of these boxes. After some testing, I found that if I use the parse script in my header file with a two second delay function, the comment box would load in the first box only.

Comment: can you post a test link?

Comment: With the following code, the comment box is displayed only in the first out of 3 divs.

Header:
<script>
setTimeout(func, 1000);
function func() {
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('subunit'));
}
</script>

WordPress page:
<script id="market" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div id="subunit">
<fb:comments href="myURL{{id}}" numposts="5" colorscheme="light" width="300"></fb:comments>
  </div>
</script>

Comment: well, you are using it for one element only. i hope you don´t use the id "subunit" more than one time, there should be no more than 1 element with the same id. id is a unique identifier. try without a parameter, just FB.XFBML.parse(); - although, i would not use a timeout, it must work right after you use the template.